# C# SAP .net connector not returning the same data as seen in SAP GUI

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I have followed the code shown on this site: "https://www.veonconsulting.com/integrating-sap-using-nco/",

I'm trying to get data from the function `BAPI_PRODORD_GET_DETAIL`, I tested `<bapi_prodord_get_detail><number>1000262</number><struct><order_objects><header>X</header><operations>X</operations><components>X</components></order_objects></struct></bapi_prodord_get_detail>`, on SAP GUI, I can see data for Header, Components & Operations, but in the code, I 'm not getting the same response, could you please help.

[image]

Code:

```
public bool testConnection()
{
  bool state = false;
  string rfcRequest = "<RFC_READ_TABLE><QUERY_TABLE>MARD</QUERY_TABLE><DELIMITER>*"
    + "</DELIMITER><ROWSKIPS>0</ROWSKIPS><ROWCOUNT>0</ROWCOUNT><TABLE><OPTIONS><ROW>"
    + "<TEXT>MATNR IN (</TEXT></ROW><ROW><TEXT>'testConnection'</TEXT></ROW><ROW>"
    + "<TEXT>)</TEXT></ROW></OPTIONS></TABLE></RFC_READ_TABLE>";

  Utils.RfcClient client = new Utils.RfcClient();
  try
  {
    XElement response = client.PullRequestToSAPrfc(rfcRequest);
    state = true;
  }
  catch (RfcLogonException ex)
  {
    Console.Write("Logon Failed");
  }
  catch (RfcInvalidStateException ex)
  {
    Console.Write("RFC Failed");
  }
  catch (RfcBaseException ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("communication error" + ex.Message);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.Write("Connection error");
  }
  finally
  {
    //client.disconnectDestination();
  }
  return state;
}

public bool testConnection()
{
  bool state = false;
  string rfcRequest = "<bapi_prodord_get_detail><number>1000262</number><struct>"
    + "<order_objects><header>X</header><operations>X</operations><components>X"
    + "</components></order_objects></struct></bapi_prodord_get_detail>";

  Utils.RfcClient client = new Utils.RfcClient();
  try
  {
    XElement response = client.PullRequestToSAPrfc(rfcRequest);
    state = true;
  }
  catch (RfcLogonException ex)
  {
    Console.Write("Logon Failed");
  }
  catch (RfcInvalidStateException ex)
  {
    Console.Write("RFC Failed");
  }
  catch (RfcBaseException ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("communication error" + ex.Message);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.Write("Connection error");
  }
  finally
  {
    //client.disconnectDestination();
  }
  return state;
}

public XElement PullRequestToSAPrfc(string XMLRequest)
{
  IRfcFunction requestFn;
  requestFn = PrepareRfcFunctionFromXML(XElement.Parse(XMLRequest));

  RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(_ECCsystem);
  requestFn.Invoke(_ECCsystem);
  RfcSessionManager.EndContext(_ECCsystem);

  XElement XMLResponse = PrepareXMLFromrfc(requestFn);

  return XMLResponse;
}

public IRfcFunction PrepareRfcFunctionFromXML(XElement xmlFunction)
{
  RfcRepository repo = _ECCsystem.Repository;
  IRfcFunction RfcFunction = repo.CreateFunction(xmlFunction.Name.ToString());
  foreach (XElement xelement in xmlFunction.Elements())
  {
    if (xelement.Name.ToString().Equals("TABLE"))
    {
      if (NotProcessSpecialTable(xelement))
        continue;
      IRfcTable options = RfcFunction.GetTable(xelement.Descendants().First().Name.ToString());
      foreach (XElement row in xelement.Elements().First().Elements())
      {
        options.Append();
        foreach (XElement rowElement in row.Elements())
        {
          string elementName = rowElement.Name.ToString();
          RfcElementMetadata elementMeta = options.GetElementMetadata(elementName);
          var elementValue = getValueAsMetadata(ref elementMeta, rowElement.Value);
          if (elementValue is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)elementValue)) { continue; }
          options.SetValue(elementName, elementValue);
        }
      }
    }
    else if (xelement.Name.ToString().Equals("STRUCT"))
    {
      IRfcStructure options = RfcFunction.GetStructure(xelement.Descendants().First().Name.ToString());
      foreach (XElement structElement in xelement.Elements().First().Elements())
      {
        string elementName = structElement.Name.ToString();
        RfcElementMetadata elementMeta = options.GetElementMetadata(elementName);
        var elementValue = getValueAsMetadata(ref elementMeta, structElement.Value);
        if (elementValue is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)elementValue)) { continue; }
        options.SetValue(elementName, elementValue);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      string elementName = xelement.Name.ToString();
      RfcElementMetadata elementMeta = RfcFunction.GetElementMetadata(elementName);
      var elementValue = getValueAsMetadata(ref elementMeta, xelement.Value);
      if (elementValue is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)elementValue)) { continue; }
      RfcFunction.SetValue(elementName, elementValue);
    }
  }
  return RfcFunction;
}

public XElement PrepareXMLFromrfc(IRfcFunction rfcFunction)
{
  var XMLRoot = new XElement(rfcFunction.Metadata.Name);
  for (int functionIndex = 0; functionIndex < rfcFunction.ElementCount; functionIndex++)
  {
    var functionMatadata = rfcFunction.GetElementMetadata(functionIndex);
    if (functionMatadata.DataType == RfcDataType.TABLE)
    {
      var rfcTable = rfcFunction.GetTable(functionMatadata.Name);
      var XMLTable = new XElement(functionMatadata.Name);
      foreach (IRfcStructure rfcStracture in rfcTable)
      {
        XElement XMLRow = new XElement("ROW");
        for (int i = 0; i < rfcStracture.ElementCount; i++)
        {
          RfcElementMetadata rfcElementMetadata = rfcStracture.GetElementMetadata(i);
          if (rfcElementMetadata.DataType == RfcDataType.BCD)
          { XMLRow.Add(new XElement(rfcElementMetadata.Name, rfcStracture.GetString(rfcElementMetadata.Name))); }
          else
          {
            XMLRow.Add(new XElement(rfcElementMetadata.Name, rfcStracture.GetString(rfcElementMetadata.Name)));
          }
        }

        XMLTable.Add(XMLRow);
      }
      XMLRoot.Add(XMLTable);
    }
    else if (functionMatadata.DataType == RfcDataType.STRUCTURE)
    {
      var rfcStructure = rfcFunction.GetStructure(functionMatadata.Name);
      XElement XMLRow = new XElement(functionMatadata.Name);
      for (int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < rfcStructure.ElementCount; elementIndex++)
      {
        RfcElementMetadata eleMeta = rfcStructure.GetElementMetadata(elementIndex);
        XMLRow.Add(new XElement(eleMeta.Name, rfcStructure.GetString(eleMeta.Name)));
      }
      XMLRoot.Add(XMLRow);
    }
    else
    {
      RfcElementMetadata rfcElement = rfcFunction.GetElementMetadata(functionIndex);
      XMLRoot.Add(new XElement(rfcElement.Name, rfcFunction.GetString(rfcElement.Name)));
    }
  }
  return XMLRoot;
}

# Below function is used for the data types.

private object getValueAsMetadata(ref RfcElementMetadata elementMeta, string value)
{
  switch (elementMeta.DataType)
  {
    case RfcDataType.BCD:
      return value;
    case RfcDataType.NUM:
      if (value.Contains("."))
      {
        int elementValue;
        int.TryParse(value, out elementValue);
        return elementValue;
      }
      else
      {
        return Convert.ToInt32(value);
      }
    case RfcDataType.INT1:
      return Convert.ToInt32(value);
    case RfcDataType.INT2:
      return Convert.ToInt32(value);
    case RfcDataType.INT4:
      return Convert.ToInt32(value);
    case RfcDataType.INT8:
      return Convert.ToInt64(value);
    case RfcDataType.CHAR:
      return value;
    case RfcDataType.DATE:
      return DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


    default:
      return string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why so many `catch` statements with the same logic? Why not have a single `catch` and do `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()`? That way you can see all the details too.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Convert.ToInt32`. Instead use `Int32.TryParse`.

Comment: @Dai I will do code enhancement, later on, right now I'm not getting the data that I see in SAP GUI which is the main issue.

Comment: Are you accessing the same system and mandant? How do you know for sure?

Comment: Hi @GregMalewski Yes I'm using the same system & details, and the given function "BAPI_PRODORD_GET_DETAIL" is inbuilt part of SAP, even you can try it, it will give same results.

Comment: out of curiosity what font is used in your SAPgui? i like it

Comment: @Suncatcher not sure, it's default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confronted to the classic issue of external and internal values in SAP.

Your screenshot shows the ABAP Function Module Test screen in SAP system. When you enter a value in the screen, it may be transformed internally before calling the function module.

These are called the **external and internal formats**. "External" is what is shown in the User Interface (typed or displayed), "internal" is the value written to the database.

For instance, imagine a database object whose primary key is a GUID, this is the object key in internal format, but in the user interface this object is always referred or shown by its name (candidate key).

In your precise case, when a Production Order is a number, the internal format always contains leading zeroes on 12 digits, and the external format does not display them. In the Function Module Test screen, if you enter this **external** value:

`1000262`

it's converted to the following **internal** value and the BAPI is called with it:

`000001000262`

Generally speaking, when you call any function module from another program, you must indicate the internal value, because there's no user interface implied between the two.

i.e., use this XML in your method `testConnection`:

```
  string rfcRequest = "<bapi_prodord_get_detail><number>000001000262</number><struct>"
    + "<order_objects><header>X</header><operations>X</operations><components>X"
    + "</components></order_objects></struct></bapi_prodord_get_detail>";
```

See also this answer about external and internal formats: [Converting MATNR via conversion exit fails for custom table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866211/converting-matnr-via-conversion-exit-fails-for-custom-table)

Comment: Thanks alot @Sandra Rossi, this was a much-needed crack, I have a question like how to find how many zeros to prepended, is this something we can see from SAP GUI? And can we pull this query "<bapi_prodord_get_detail><number>000001000262</number><struct>"
    + "<order_objects><header>X</header><operations>X</operations><components>X"
    + "</components></order_objects></struct></bapi_prodord_get_detail>" from SAP GUI.

Comment: It can be found difficultly: an ABAP developer can run the BAPI function module in debug mode and display the actual content of the input parameter, or users usually know the database tables where the objects are stored (AUFK-AUFNR). Things are not straight-forward because BAPI function modules usually expect the external value (like WBS numbers, country codes, etc.) The Function Module Test screen doesn't provide a way to export the XML representation of parameters entered.

Comment: @Mysterious288 actually I created an [idea](https://influence.sap.com/sap/ino/#/idea/256743) (sort of feature request to SAP) to implement this conversion automatically on SDK level without any additional efforts on your side, if you like it you can vote for it

Comment: @Suncatcher The vote button is disabled for me.

Comment: yep, seems they have closed this idea because it doesn't fit their roadmap

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do the required field conversions programmatically, which are explained in Sandra Rossi's answer, you may use the RFMs BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT, BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1, BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT and BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1 for doing so.
However, every additional RFC call has of course a negative impact on the performance.

Besides, SAP Note [206068](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/206068) is a good resource for an explanation of some RFC BAPI pitfalls which you also stepped in.